# UI not update after delete mutation in apollo client v3.0.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, frontend, apollo-client

**Spesification**

Library

1. @apollo/client": "^3.0.0"
2. React.JS

GraphQL query : GET_ALL_USERS

```
query($input: GetAllUserInput) {
        getAllUsers(input: $input) {
            totalPages
            currentPage
            totalItems
            rows {
                email
                username
                created_dtm
                status
                group_id
            }
        }
    }
```

GraphQL Mutation : DELETE_USER

```
mutation($username: String!) {
    deleteUser(username: $username) {
        username
    }
}
```

**Problem**

1.When I'm click on Delete Button, UI doesn't update but in the backend, item successfully deleted

```
const TableUserInfo = ({ data }) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

  const handleShowModal = () => setShowModal(true);
  const handleCloseModal = () => setShowModal(false);

  const userIdtoDelete = data.getAllUsers.rows.map((row) => row.username);
  const userIdToString = userIdtoDelete.toString();

  const [deleteUser, { error, loading, refetch }] = useMutation(DELETE_USER, {
    variables: { username: userIdToString },
    update(cache, { data }) {
      const { getAllUsers } = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_ALL_USERS });

      cache.writeQuery({
        query: GET_ALL_USERS,
        data: {
          getAllUsers: getAllUsers.filter(
            (user) => user.username !== userIdToString
          ),
        },
      });
    },
    onCompleted: () => {
      refetch();
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
    },
  });
...
      <Button
                key="Hapus"
                variant="outline-danger"
                onClick={deleteUser}
                disabled={loading}
                className="d-block btn-block btn-sm mb-2 w-100"
              >
                Hapus
              </Button>
```

Additional Info : Data comes from parent. here is the parent code :

```
const PengaturanPengguna = () => {
  // pagination
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const sizeFetchDataPerPage = 10;

  const { data, refetch, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_ALL_USERS, {
    variables: {
      input: {
        size: sizeFetchDataPerPage,
        page: currentPage,
      },
    },
  });

  const totalPages = data?.getAllUsers.totalPages;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setCurrentPage(data?.getAllUsers.currentPage);
    }
  }, [data])

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error)
    return (
      <p>
        Error... {error.message} {console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2))}{" "}
      </p>
    );

  // refetch data
  const handleRefreshClick = () => {
    refetch();
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <CardInfo data={data} />
      <Card>
        <Card.Title>
          <span className="base-md text-regular mt-2 std-txt-primary-200">
            Data Pengguna Dashboard
          </span>
        </Card.Title>
        <Card.Body>
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <Form inline>
              <Search />
              <Button variant='secondary' onClick={handleRefreshClick} disabled={loading}>{loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Muat Ulang'}</Button>
            </Form>
            <div>
              <Button variant="success">Daftar Akun</Button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <TableUserInfo data={data} /> //heres the table
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div className="align-self-center">
              <span>Keterangan : </span>
              <StyledDiv>
                <Legend color="#40B4BA" />
                <StyledSpan>Aktif</StyledSpan>
              </StyledDiv>
              <StyledDiv>
                <Legend color="#78909C" />
                <StyledSpan>Tidak Aktif</StyledSpan>
              </StyledDiv>
            </div>
            <PageNavigator
              totalPages={totalPages}
              currentPage={currentPage}
              setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}
            />
          </div>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

2. I got this error information
   [image]

**What I've Tried**
I'm using refetchQueries, update method with cache.readQuery() and cache.writeQuery but UI still doesn't update.

**Question**
How to make delete mutation deleted data in the backend and update the UI based on my query and mutation spesification ?

**Update**
Now, when i'm using deleteUser mutation directly onClick button, i'm getting this errors :
[image]

and here's the code :

```
  const [deleteUser, { error, loading, refetch }] = useMutation(DELETE_USER);


 <Button
                key="Hapus"
                variant="outline-danger"
                onClick={() => {
                  const userToDelete = user.username;

                  deleteUser({
                    variables: { username: userToDelete },
                    update(cache, { data }) {
                      const { getAllUsers } = cache.readQuery({
                        query: GET_ALL_USERS,
                        variables,
                      });

                      cache.writeQuery({
                        query: GET_ALL_USERS,
                        variables,
                        getAllUsers: {
                          ...getAllUsers,
                          totalItems: getAllUsers.totalItems - 1,
                          rows: getAllUsers.rows.filter((user) => user.username !== userToDelete)
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    onCompleted: () => {
                      refetch();
                    },
                    onError: (error) => {
                      console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
                    },
                  });
                }}
                disabled={loading}
                className="d-block btn-block btn-sm mb-2 w-100"
              >
                Hapus
              </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read/write a query from the cache you must pass the same variables as the orinigal query, and to do that you can use the `variables` returned from the original query:

*Parent component*

```
const { data, refetch, loading, error, variables } = useQuery(GET_ALL_USERS, {
    variables: {
      input: {
        size: sizeFetchDataPerPage,
        page: currentPage,
      },
    },
  });

...

<TableUserInfo data={data} variables={variables} /> //heres the table

...
```

*Child component*

```
const TableUserInfo = ({ data, variables }) => {

...

const { getAllUsers } = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_ALL_USERS, variables });

cache.writeQuery({
  query: GET_ALL_USERS,
  variables,
  data: {
    getAllUsers: getAllUsers.filter(
      (user) => user.username !== userIdToString
    ),
  },
});

...
```

Also I think this part of the code is wrong:

```
const userIdtoDelete = data.getAllUsers.rows.map((row) => row.username);
const userIdToString = userIdtoDelete.toString();

...

data: {
          getAllUsers: getAllUsers.filter(
            (user) => user.username !== userIdToString
          ),
},
```

First you access `row` property of `getAllUsers`, you return an array of `username` then you use `.toString()` in this array, but when you update the cache you use `.filter` directly on `getAllUsers` and you compare the `username` property with the stringified array of `username` (`userIdToString`), so I think you should verify this part for possible mistakes

Comment: thanks for the answer sir, so, for the wrong code, how to fix it ? i don't have any idea. thankyou sir

Comment: You have to select only the username of the user you want to delete and I think you must use filter on `rows`: `getAllUsers.rows.filter(user => user.username !== selectedUsername)`,

Comment: thanks for the answer sir, now my question has edited. can you spot the error sir ?

Comment: the error says that `getAllUsers` from the cache is undefined, are you sure you've passed the returned `variables` from `useQuery(GET_ALL_USERS...` to the `TableUserInfo` component?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are missing the rows here:

```
 getAllUsers: {
   ...getAllUsers,
   totalItems: getAllUsers.totalItems - 1,
   rows: getAllUsers.rows.filter((user) => user.username !== userIdToString)
 },
```

Comment: thanks for the answer sir, now my question has edited. can you spot the error sir ?